# How to insert long-format data into two separate tables using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have selected the following data that I want to insert into the database.

| Letter | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |

Since there is a repetition of "A" and "B" in this format, I want to split data into two separate tables: table1 and table2.

table1:

| ID | Letter |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

ID here is automatically inserted by database (using a sequence).

table2:

| table1_id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

In this particular example, I don't gain anything on storage but it illustrates in the best way what problem I have encountered.

How can I use SQL or PL/SQL to insert data into table1 and table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First populate table1 from the source

```
insert table1(Letter)
select distinct Letter
from srcTable;
```

Then load data from the source decoding letter to id

```
insert table2(table1_id, Value)
select t1.id, src.value
from srcTable src
join table1 t1 on t1.Letter = src.Letter;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use multitable insert with workaround to get stable `nextval` on sequence. Since `nextval` is evaluated on each row regardless of `when` condition, it is not sufficient to use it inside `values`.

> ```
> insert all
>   when rn = 1 then into l(id, val) values(seq, letter)
>   when rn > 0 then into t(l_id, val) values(seq, val)
>
> with a(letter, val) as (
>   select 'A', 1 from dual union all
>   select 'A', 2 from dual union all
>   select 'B', 3 from dual union all
>   select 'B', 4 from dual union all
>   select 'C', 5 from dual
> )
> , b as (
>   select
>     a.*,
>     l.id as l_id,
>     row_number() over(partition by a.letter order by a.val asc) as rn
>   from a
>     left join l
>       on a.letter = l.val
> )
>
> select
>   b.*,
>   max(decode(rn, 1, coalesce(
>         l_id,
>         extractvalue(
>           /*Hide the reference to the sequence due to restrictions
>           of multitalbe insert*/
>           dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype('select l_sq.nextval as seq from dual')
>           , '/ROWSET/ROW/SEQ/text()'
>         ) + 0
>       ))
>   ) over(partition by b.letter) as seq
> from b
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from l
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | VAL
> -: | :--
>  1 | A  
>  2 | B  
>  3 | C
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from t
> ```
>
> ```
> L_ID | VAL
> ---: | --:
>    1 |   1
>    1 |   2
>    2 |   3
>    2 |   4
>    3 |   5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fb7429b8371f2e25c911c77e853388a)*

Answer (score 0):

Principally you need to produce and ID value for the `table1` to be inserted into `table2`. For this, You can use `INSERT ... RETURNING ID INTO v_id` statement after creating the tables containing some constraints especially unique ones such as `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE`

```
CREATE TABLE table1( ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, letter VARCHAR2(1) NOT NULL );
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT uk_tab1_letter UNIQUE(letter);
CREATE TABLE table2( ID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, table1_id INT, value INT );
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_tab2_tab1_id FOREIGN KEY(table1_id) REFERENCES table1 (ID);
```

and adding exception handling in order not to insert repeating letters to the first table. Then use the following code block ;

```
DECLARE
  v_id     table1.id%TYPE;
  v_letter table1.letter%TYPE := 'A';
  v_value  table2.value%TYPE := 1;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1(letter) VALUES(v_letter) RETURNING ID INTO v_id;
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  END;
  
  INSERT INTO table2(table1_id,value) SELECT id,v_value FROM table1 WHERE letter = v_letter;
  COMMIT;
END;  
/
```

and run by changing the initialized values for `v_letter`&`v_value` as `'A'`&`2`, `'B'`&`1`,`'B'`&`2` ..etc respectively.

Alternatively you can convert the code block to a stored procedure or function such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Pr_Ins_Tabs( 
                                         v_letter table1.letter%TYPE, 
                                         v_value  table2.value%TYPE 
                                       ) AS
  v_id     table1.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1(letter) VALUES(v_letter) RETURNING ID INTO v_id;
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
  END;
  
  INSERT INTO table2(table1_id,value) SELECT id,v_value FROM table1 WHERE letter = v_letter;
  COMMIT;
END;  
/
```

in order to revoke resiliently such as

```
BEGIN
 Pr_Ins_Tabs('A',2);
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=202e853fcc12947b3ae74e21e7787cd5)</kbd>

PS. *If your DB verion is prior to 12c, then create sequences(`seq1`&`seq2`) and use `seq1.nextval`&`seq2.nextval` within the Insert statements as not possible to use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` clause within the table creation DDL statements.*